# How to insert extra element before an iteration without affecting the distance between existing printed elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, printing, string-formatting

Input:

```
a = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Syntax:

```
for i in a:
    print(f'{i:<14}', end = '')
```

Current output:

```
x             y             z
```

Expected output

```
Title                                   x             y             z
```

Comment: This is a pretty basic question that you already seem to know the answer to. I am therefore voting to close due to either lack of research/knowledge of the language/ or forethought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print `"Title"` before the loop:

```
print("Title", end=' ' * 25)
for i in a:
    print(f'{i:<14}', end = '')
```

Output:

```
Title                         x             y             z
```